# Terrain creation error using a GeoTIFF file with HEC-RAS 6.2 - "object reference not set to instance of object"

Tags: qgis, hydrology, raster-conversion, terrain, hec-ras

I am attempting to import a TIFF file created in QGIS, into HEC-RAS. I have a projection file as the SRS definition for HEC-RAS, which is derived from a shapefile that lines up with the spatial extent of the TIFF. During the creation process, the first two steps complete as normal but then I receive an error: "object reference not set to instance of object".

My filepaths do not contain spaces or special characters and I verified the georeferencing was correct by inspecting with gdalinfo beforehand.

[image: error message]
[image: visual of geotiff]
[image: georeferencing info]

I do not know what is causing this to happen.

Comment: @Jeff Becker I changed my projection file to the text you've attached here, but I get a more cryptic looking "ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations" message. 

For some strange reason, I am able to generate the terrain on my other PC, using the same version of Windows and hec-ras with the georeferencing I originally had in the prj file.

Comment: I agree this was not a problem in HEC-RAS 5. In the past exporting GeoTIFF files from Civil 3D for HEC-RAS 6, I was able to work around this by trying Create New RAS Terrain a second time and selecting one of the intermediate TIF files in the HEC-RAS Terrain sub-folder. But that's not working for me with the GeoTIFF I have from QGIS. Still no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime back I ran into a similar problem, and yes there are hardly any solutions available on the web. I would suggest, retry using this projection:

PROJCS["NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 14N",GEOGCS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2011",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1116"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6318"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-99],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",1640416.66666667],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["US Survey Foot",0.304800609601219],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]

Let me know if it works out.

Also, you can probably shift to GeoHECRAS software, it’s also based on RAS engine, plus they have a vast tech support team readily available so you don’t have to wait for finding a solution.

Comment: That's not helping me.

Comment: Also, GeoHECRAS software costs dozens of thousands of dollars. That makes your suggestion seem kind of spammy.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem since version 6. A colleague told me today to pause Dropbox while I create a New HEC-RAS Terrain. That seems to have solved my issue. So for me it was a file locking issue or similar.